# jQuery value of div (object)

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
var lastMessage = $('.message:last');
```

.message is a div, I could use .html() to get the valueo f it, but I want the WHOLE div.
Example:

```
<div class="message">Content Here</div>
```

I don't want the 'Content Here', I want `'<div class="message">Content Here</div>'`.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: if this div have parent div you can select this parents html.

Comment: It does have a parent div, but <div id="parent"></div> have more than one <div class="message"></div> - so it would get the value of all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var html = $('<div>').append($('.message:last').clone()).remove().html();
```

It's a little convoluted, but it is creating a new `div`, cloning the full `.message:last` div within that, then returning the HTML of the new div, which now includes your original `.message` element.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bM4Zs/)

Comment: Why `.remove()` the new `<div>`?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery doesn't have anything in its API to do this directly, but you can use the native `.outerHTML` property.

```
var lastMessage = $('.message:last');

var html = lastMessage[0].outerHTML; // [0] gives you the native DOM element
```

---

...but Firefox doesn't support this, so you can do something like this...

```
// First try outerHTML------v    
var html = lastMessage[0].outerHTML || $('<div>').append(lastMessage.clone()).html();
```

---

...or an entire non-jQuery solution could be...

```
// First try outerHTML------v    
var html = lastMessage[0].outerHTML || 
           document.createElement('div')
                    .appendChild(lastMessage[0].cloneNode(true))
                    .parentNode
                    .innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clone it and append to a div, then get the html.

```
$("<div/>").append($('.message:last').clone()).html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a simple function to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/KugwB/

The way it works is that it clones the element, then appends it to a temporary `div`. It then returns the inner HTML of that temporary `div`.

Answer (score -1):

```
var lastMessage = $('.message:last').clone();
```

Will create a complete copy of the DOM node.

Answer (score -1):

You should have a div, which is blank in the meantime, say `<div id="blank">`, then you can do this:

```
$("#blank").append('<div class="message">Content Here</div>');
```